# How generate custom ouput file names?

Tags: hadoop

I have doubt on output file name generation. I am using Hadoop-0.19.2 and I have two input files on input folder(/data/inp/20111203_12345,/data/inp/20111204_12345) and I wanted to generate the outputs corresponding output folder of ( /data/out/20111203_12345/part-0000X , /data/out/20111204_12345/part-0000x)

The Map Reduce program gets invoked only one time.

Comment: What's your question...? How does it involve programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the input and the output files, it can be assumed that there is no merging of the data across input files.

1) In the mapper, do some processing and output the KV pairs as filePath/value. Then the all data for a particular file will go to a single mapper. In the mapper implement the following to get the filePath

```
void configure(JobConf conf) {
    filePath = conf.get("map.input.file");
}
```

Note that filePath includes the input file name including the directory.

2) [MultipleOutputformat](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleOutputFormat.html) allows to write data to multiple files and the output file name can be derived from the output KV pairs. The keys for the reducer will be the input file directory and name, which can be used for derive the output file name.

Using the above approach, the reducer might be a bottle-neck if the input file is large, as each reducer will be processing data from a single file. I could not think of a better way of doing this :)